# IDE for react with .net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, ide, visual-studio-code

I try to find out what is the best way to develop react app with .net web api as the api service.
I realized that using visual studio 2015 won't work since its lack of es6 support.

I really liked atom as the "client" side programming and visual studio 2015 but I foresee issues working with 2 IDEs opened, especially for those whose computer is not strong enough..
I have also heard of visual studio code but I don't have much experience with it and how exactly to debug in it.

Would like to here your suggestions, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 2 IDE's opened?

Comment: I'm still using vs 2015 for backend development and vscode for frontend stuff. If you want to try out vscode for react debugging check out this [boilerplate](https://github.com/skolmer/react-hot-boilerplate-vscode). For asp.net web api Visual Studio 2015 has still the best tooling support.

Comment: I meant visual studio for backend development and atom for frontend development. I work in a fullstack developers team so that means both will probably be opened simultaneously..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Rider from jetbrains - A fast & powerful,
cross-platform .NET IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/).
I use that IDE daily and have support for ES6 and JSX Typescript and more.